# How do I make my class objects return an array instead of <Classobject:0x007fc94a0...]>?

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, initialization

!!!! I'm cleaning up my code and rethinking my question. I'll repost and edited version in a few minutes. Thanks for the responses!

Here's my code:

```
class Student
   attr_accessor :scores, :first_name

  def initialize(first_name, scores)    
    @first_name = first_name
    @scores = scores
  end

  def average
   @scores.inject {|sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / @scores.size
  end

  def letter_grade
    case average
    when (90..100)
    "A"
        when (80..89)
    "B"
    when (70..79)
    "C"
    when (60..69)
    "D"
    when (0..59)
    "F"
    end
  end
end

me        = Student.new("Alex", [100,100,100,0,100])
student_2 = Student.new('Hodor', [2,2,7,0,90])
student_3 = Student.new('Aria', [90,100,87,90,90])
student_4 = Student.new('Tyrion', [95,100,97,100,30])
student_5 = Student.new('Jaela', [100,100,100,100,100])

students = [me, student_2, student_3, student_4, student_5]

p students
```

Here's what I get back:

```
[#<Student:0x007f92a91e6070 @first_name="Alex", @scores=[100, 100, 100, 0, 100]>, #<Student:0x007f92a91e5ff8 @first_name="Hodor", @scores=[2, 2, 7, 0, 90]>, #<Student:0x007f92a91e5f80 @first_name="Aria", @scores=[90, 100, 87, 90, 90]>, #<Student:0x007f92a91e5f08 @first_name="Tyrion", @scores=[95, 100, 97, 100, 30]>, #<Student:0x007f92a91e5e90 @first_name="Jaela", @scores=[100, 100, 100, 100, 100]>]
```

I want something like [["Alex", [100, 100, 100, 0, 100], ["Hodor", [2..]..]]

The goal is to have these tests pass:

```
p linear_search(students, "Alex") == 0
p linear_search(students, "NOT A STUDENT") == -1
```

So I actually need this to happen within the Student class, I think.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: The goal is to be able to search through the students array by names. I added the tests I need to pass above and the search function. Its an assessment challenge for school.

Comment: You can write `@scores.inject {|sum, el| sum + el }` as `@scores.inject(:+)`.  Check the doc for [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aka `reduce`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of the exercise, but to get from your actual output to your expected output, you just have to go over your elements, and build an array out of each one (use [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)):

```
students.map { |x| [x.first_name, x.scores] }
# => [["Alex", [100, 100, 100, 0, 100]], ["Hodor", [2, 2, 7, 0, 90]], ["Aria", [90, 100, 87, 90, 90]], ["Tyrion", [95, 100, 97, 100, 30]], ["Jaela", [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]]]
```

Comment: I figured this out finally! I used .map. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to output an instance of Student, ruby calls to_s() on the Student instance.  If your class does not provide a to_s() method, then the inherited to_s() method(in class Object) is called, which provides the string you see.  If you redefine Object#to_s, you can prove that:

```
#Your code here

class Object
  def to_s
    'hello from Object#to_s'
  end
end

p students

--output:--
[hello from Object#to_s,
 hello from Object#to_s,
 hello from Object#to_s,
 hello from Object#to_s,
 hello from Object#to_s]
```

If you override the to_s() method inside Student, then ruby will call it and use its return value whenever you try to output a Student object:

```
require 'pp'

class Student

  attr_accessor :scores, :first_name
  ...

  def to_s
    "#{first_name} #{scores.inspect}"
  end

end



students = [
  Student.new("Alex", [100,100,100,0,100]),
  Student.new('Hodor', [2,2,7,0,90]),
  Student.new('Aria', [90,100,87,90,90]),
  Student.new('Tyrion', [95,100,97,100,30]),
  Student.new('Jaela', [100,100,100,100,100]),
]

pp students

--output:--
[Alex [100, 100, 100, 0, 100],
 Hodor [2, 2, 7, 0, 90],
 Aria [90, 100, 87, 90, 90],
 Tyrion [95, 100, 97, 100, 30],
 Jaela [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]]
```

In the code fragment `scores.inspect` the inspect() method is what `p` uses, i.e. `p scores` is equivalent to `print scores.inspect + "\n"`.  But you can't write:

```
"some string #{p.scores}"
```

because string interpolation uses the return value of `p.scores`, and `p`, like `puts`, always returns nil.